# ng-repeat does not work declaring my model with Object.create

Tags: javascript, angularjs, clone

Why the ng-repeat does not work declaring my model with Object.create.

In the example bellow i am declaring two models. But when i try to declare the second one with Object.create does not work the iteration:

```
$scope.model1 = model;                //Work
$scope.model2 = Object.create(model); //Not working
```

Here the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3795/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using `Object` wrong, change your code to this,

```
$scope.model2 = Object(model);
```

but if you want clone/copy your object use angular.copy here is a link to [DOCUMENTATION](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)...

```
$scope.model2 = angular.copy(model);
```

Comment: Ah, ok. But that does not solve my problem. Because if i change a propertie of the model1 affect into the model2. How i can clone the model to have separated instances?